# RESTful way to operation

Tags: rest

I want to have RESTful interface which does not break REST principles. This is more discussion question how would you do it and what do you see as the best solution. Imagine this application scenario.

Application has typical users and rooms where they gather to interact. Each HTTP request includes HTTP basic authentication headers which brings information which user interacts with resource. Lets think of resource of rooms under /rooms URL. I want to have RESTful method+URI to take care of actions when user creates room (and does NOT joins him, only provides data who can join this room), joins room and lefts rooms. What came to my mind is:

Create room

```
POST /rooms --data {room data}
```

Join and leave room migh look like code below,

```
PUT/DELETE /rooms/{roomId}/{userId}
```

As you can see, I need to pass userId which should be context information from HTTP headers, so I should not pass it in URL I guess. The problem that is here, that during creation of room I got users in room, but they have "not_joined" state. So after creation (no join performed so far), there actually IS /rooms/{roomId}/{userId} resource. Any idea how to do it nicely?:-)

Comment: to make it more clear, Im adding example: post /rooms {"allowedUsers":["tom", "joe", "jane"]} (lets say that tom, joe and jane are userIds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resource is **A** room so firstly you must consider :

```
POST /room
```

Without the **'s'**. The response will return the **Content-Location : /room/{roomId}** header which indicates you the room URI.

```
GET /rooms
```

Lists all the rooms.

Then you can consider a resource URI for join action :

```
/room/{roomId}/join/{joinId}
```

For a user to join a particular room :

```
POST /room/{roomId}/join --data <join userId="{userId}" />
Response header : **Content-Location : /room/{roomId}/join/{joinId}**
```

And for a user to leave a particular room :

```
DELETE /room/{roomId}/join/{joinId}
```

For a list of 'joins' of a particular room :

```
GET /room/{roomId}/joins
Response content : 
<joins>
 <join id="888" userId="100" />
 <join id="889" userId="101" />
 <join id="890" userId="102" />
</joins>
```

For a particular user :

```
GET /user/{userId} 
Response content : 
<user id="100" name="john" />
```

For allowed users :

```
POST /room/{roomId}/allowed 
--data 
<allowed>
 <user id="100">
 <user id="101">
 <user id="102">
 <user id="103">
</allowed>
```

Comment: Good, but I would suggest 'POST /rooms' (with the **s**) - there is no need to create different structures with singular names. '/rooms/1', /rooms/1/joins/tom' would work better.

Comment: Thx a lot Mickael. Looks fine. I must say that I already thought of it (joins), because same structure is held within DB. I will wait for other responses. Btw agree with Arsen7, POST /rooms is i guess more "standard" way in RESTful apporach, but again thx for good reply:-)

Comment: @dxxx: Mickaël's answer is good. I was writing almost the same answer, but he was faster ;-)

Comment: The more "standard" way is to keep "room" and not "rooms". Your resource is a room not a list of rooms. When you send POST /room you tell the server to create a room resource. /rooms URI represents another resource.

Comment: Um, I must disagree a bit. Im not saying that wiki absolutely correct but the same way as it is written there, they learn me it in university. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services

Comment: I learned this from the book **"REST in Practice"**. But I understand your point of you. There is no really REST "standard" but I like thinking in term of resources.

Comment: Yep:-) It is propably point of view. Anyway thx for help. Marking this answer as correct. Again thank you both Michael and Arsen7 ;-)

Comment: @Mickaël: I would like to defend the '/rooms' a little, if you don't mind. ;-) POST request is used to **"add a resource to the collection"**, and '/rooms' represents **the collection**. There is no '/room' resource - what would it return in response to GET request? A single room is the resource at '/rooms/1', so I am still sure that the plural names are better in this case. Of course '/room' could represent the "current room of the requesting user", but such scenario is not mentioned in this thread.

Comment: I understand your point of you. `GET /room` for me will return all rooms list. I would use this URI for some search too. `/room?nbUsersBiggerThan=10` for instance. I don't especially see an URI as a resource Tree.

Comment: @Mickaël The convention you are using seems to have sprung up from web frameworks that try to stuff both the list resource and the single item resource into just one controller.  (e.g. Show and Index)  Although convenient at first, I do not believe it produces the most intuitive results nor is it a great idea in my opinion to generate a list resource and a single entity resource from one controller.